# How to sync two dropdown lists with different display in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a list of countries, with `key`, `value`, `text`.
I would like to have two `Dropdown` (https://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown/) list, one shows the `key`, the other the `text`.

The goal is to allow to choose by key of by text (we can type in the dropdown); if I update one, the other is synchronized immediately.

How can I achieve this ?

```
      <Dropdown
        id='form-input-country'
        label='Country'
        placeholder='Select Country'
        fluid
        search
        selection
        options={countryISOOptions} // will show text
      />
      <Dropdown
        id='form-input-country'
        label='Country'
        placeholder='Select Country'
        fluid
        search
        selection
        options={countryISOOptions} // want to show key + want to sync in both direction
      />
```

I import `countryISOOptions` which looks like:

```
export const countryISOOptions = [
{key: 'AF', value: '4', text: 'Afghanistan'},
{key: 'AL', value: '8', text: 'Albania'},
{key: 'DZ', value: '12', text: 'Algeria'},
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maintain 2 option arrays. One for text and other for keys(derived from the first options array). Then maintain just **one** `state` and an `onChange` for both dropdowns and you will be fine.

See [working copy of your code](https://codesandbox.io/s/sync-2-dropdown-semantic-ui-react-c9lzo?file=/src/App.js).

**See code snippet:**

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Dropdown } from "semantic-ui-react";
import "./styles.css";
const countryISOOptions = [
  { key: "AF", value: "4", text: "Afghanistan" },
  { key: "AL", value: "8", text: "Albania" },
  { key: "DZ", value: "12", text: "Algeria" }
];

const countryKeys = countryISOOptions.map(({ key, value }) => ({
  value,
  text: key
}));

export default function App() {
  const [text, setText] = useState("");
  const onChangeTextDropdown = (e, d) => {
    console.log("onChangeTextDropdown", e.target.value);
    console.log("d", d);
    setText(d.value);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <Dropdown
        id="form-input-countryz"
        label="Country"
        placeholder="Select Country - text"
        value={text}
        onChange={onChangeTextDropdown}
        fluid
        search
        selection
        options={countryISOOptions} // will show text
      />
      <Dropdown
        id="form-input-country"
        label="Country"
        placeholder="Select Country - key"
        value={text}
        onChange={onChangeTextDropdown}
        fluid
        search
        selection
        options={countryKeys} // want to show key + want to sync in both direction
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: It seems that this library did not implement a way to map the current label for a single selection. The prop "renderLabel" is available only for multiples

Answer (score 0):

If you are using controlled version, then each `Dropdown` is a typical `Input`that supports two props called `value` and `onChange`. I'll use hook in the following example,

```
  const [value1, setValue1] = setState('')
  const [value2, setValue2] = setState('')
  const onValue1Change = e => {
     const value = e.target.value
     setValue1(value)
     if (value === 'key') setValue2('country')
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <Dropdown
        value={value1}
        onChange={onValue1Change}
        ...
      />
      <Dropdown
        value={value2}
        ...
      />
    </div>
  )
```